# Hibernate Mapping: referencing a set of Entities with OneToMany and one Entity of that set with OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to implement a Hibernate-relation, where an Entity A references a set of Entites B via `@OneToMany`. One of these said Entites `B` might have a special role and should therefore (optionally) be also referenced by `A` via `@OneToOne`.

Entity A:

```
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group")
    private List<GroupMember> members = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupSpokesman")
    private GroupMember spokesman;
}
```

Entity B:

```
public class GroupMember {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupId")
    private Group group;
}
```

Table `group`:

```
id | groupSpokesman | ...
```

The column `groupSpokesman` references the ID of that `GroupMember`, which is elected as a spokesman. If one of the GroupMembers is a Spokesman, he should remain in the set of GroupMembers. The column might be `NULL`, if no spokesman is elected and all GroupMembers are treated equally.

Table `groupMember`:

```
id | groupId | ...
```

The column `groupId` references the ID of the group, to which the `GroupMember` belongs.

Hibernate successfully saves the Entities. If none of the GroupMembers is a Spokesman, everything works fine. But as soon as one of the Entites in `Group.members` is also assigned to `Group.spokesman`, Hibernate sets the foreign key `GroupMember.group` for that particular GroupMember to `NULL`, which means that the Spokesman is no longer member of the Group. The foreign key `Group.spokesman` is correctly set to the ID of the Spokesman.

Comment: I think you should add another propriety into GroupMember, an example `Group groupSpokesman` and in the mapping one to one `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "groupSpokesman", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the result remains the same with this additional property + mapping.

Comment: also, when your GroupMember is also spokesman the id is the same if the GroupMember exists in the DB, hibernate for not violate the constraint id = unique, set the id to list ad null, if my reasoning is right, I think you add the JoinColum to the same id. It is just a reasoning not having the original code I can't test it, so I try to share the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping as shown in my initial post seems to be fine. The problem only occurs, if Entity A and all mapped Entities B are saved at once, e.g.

```
Group g = new Group();

GroupMember gm1 = new GroupMember();
GroupMember gm2 = new GroupMember();

g.addGroupMember(gm1); // gm1.group is null
g.addGroupMember(gm2);

g.setGroupSpokesman(gm1);

repository.save(g);
```

As soon, as I save the entity twice (first time before setting the group-spokesman; second time after that), everything works as expected:

```
Group g = new Group();

GroupMember gm1 = new GroupMember(); // gm1.group is set to ID of g
GroupMember gm2 = new GroupMember();

g.addGroupMember(gm1);
g.addGroupMember(gm2);

repository.save(g);

g.setGroupSpokesman(gm1);

repository.save(g);
```

Still, this looks like a workaround to me.